# English translation (and source) of the Sanskrit shloka from Prabhupada's commentary on SB 3.20.18

Tags: identification-request, shloka, vishnu-purana, prabhupada, translation

Srila Prabhupada quotes the following shloka(s) from Viṣṇu Purāṇa in his commentary on [Srimad Bhagavatam 3.20.18](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/20/18/), but he did not give us the English translation.

So I'd like to know the precise English translation of the following. And the verse number too from Viṣṇu Purāṇa.

> Especially in this Age of Kali, everyone is overwhelmed by the madness to accumulate paraphernalia for material enjoyment. These definitions are very nicely given in Viṣṇu Purāṇa, wherein it is said:
>
> > tamo ’viveko mohaḥ syād 
> > antaḥ-karaṇa-vibhramaḥ 
> > mahā-mohas tu vijñeyo 
> > grāmya-bhoga-sukhaiṣaṇā
> >
> > maraṇaṁ hy andha-tāmisraṁ 
> > tāmisraṁ krodha ucyate 
> > avidyā pañca-parvaiṣā 
> > prādurbhūtā mahātmanaḥ

Comment: it seems to be 1.5.5 (though all words are not matching but it might be commentary on this verse), it's translation can be found [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp039.htm#fn_168)..

Comment: Dear YDS, Thank you for your kindly concerning to my inquiry. I took a look t the site you pasted, but I unfortunately do not have the ability to find the one which I need to know. Could you please point out which one you meant to?

Comment: "tamo moho mahāmohas tāmisro hy andhasaṃjñitaḥ /
avidyā pañcaparvaiṣā prādurbhūtā mahātmanaḥ // ViP_1,5.5 //"

Comment: Thank you for your concern.I took a look at Viṣṇu Purāṇa 1.5.5 in devanagali. But they are not the same verse which I need to translation. But thank you for your help.